# Why SELinux policy in /sepolicy and /sys/fs/selinux/policy do not match?

Tags: embedded-linux, android-source, selinux, android-kernel, libselinux

I'm using Android SELinux enforced device and doing the following:

```
adb pull /sepolicy sepolicy1
adb pull /sys/fs/selinux/policy sepolicy2
diff sepolicy1 sepolicy2
```

I get:

```
Binary files sepolicy1 and sepolicy2 differ
```

From examining with a hex viewer it seems similar in few parts but mostly different.

Why its different?
What does that mean?

Comment: This is probably not the best place to ask, you might try unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `sediff` (SELinux policy difference tool) to compare the policy files. diff is unable to directly compare the files due to non-semantic differences in the two policy images (e.g. ordering issues).